# Eclipse: Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7

I have Eclipse Indigo installed on Win7 64bit with the ADT plugin and Android SDK's installed.

An error occurs when I have my emulator open and I try to launch my test application:

```
Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
```

I have looked into this error and it most often appears to be a firewall issue but with the firewall turned off I still get the error. Would it have anything to do with me having another Eclipse based IDE installed (Aptana 3)?

Things I have tried so far:

- Turn firewall off
- changed ddms port to 8601
- checked localhost is set to 127.0.01

I'm running out of ideas so any help of suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011539/failed-to-initialize-monitor-thread-unable-to-establish-loopback-connection

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I suspect Java 7 which looks like it uses IPV6 in preference

Answer (score 26):

No need to disable IPV6. Just force Eclipse to use IPV4. 
Edit eclipse.ini and add the last line:

```
openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: To anyone searching, my error started after I installed Avast as my antivirus/firewall protection.

Comment: @EmRa228 thank you . I was struggle with same problem. I solve it by your answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution : turn off Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface.

This probably converts IP4 to IPv6 addresses or something, resulting in an IPv6 address for your localhost (strange though, that a PING still results in IP4). Anyway, turning it off (Device manager > View > Show hidden devices > right click on Teredo > disable) solves the problem!

I found out by doing a ipconfig /all in the NON working situation. It showed :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:####:###:####:####(Preferred)

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c47:###:####:#### (Preferred)
```

//edit : I guess it's technically a workaround untill Eclipse supports IPv6

Answer (score 1):

Ahah!!
Finally fixed this one.
It was a problem I believe with my bigfoot killer network

So, here is what I did.

Open CMD as administrator ( Right click, open as administrator )
Type: "netsh winsock reset"

Restart the computer

When it comes up saying:
"Your LSP is not mapped correctly, would you like to re map it?"
Click "NO"

Then all is well..

Only now, I do have it asking me about LSP mapping each time I boot, this f

Comment: This worked for me! Any thoughts on how to make the Bigfoot Adaptor play nice (and not have to click that LSP mapping each time)?

Answer (score 1):

Was the same problem, tried everything and only completely deleted Java 7 and installed Java 6 JDK solved problem!

Comment: If this answer was useful, Please accept to help other users find the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Killer Networks Wireless card N-1103. I found that installing the latest driver from their website cured it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Eclipse is blocked...

Go to command prompt and to `/tools` directory and type:

```
adb kill-server 
adb start-server
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I've tried this both through command line and the device view and it still has the same problem. The error now also appears when I open eclipse not just when I try launch the application.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here.  My problem was a firewall issue.  I use VirtualBox sometimes and found that the virtual machine's network adapter was the roadblock.  Disabling the virtual adapter in Windows device manager solved my issue.