# Android running error

Tags: android, android-x86

I have been facing a real strange problem. I have installed and used android many times and even now using it on my desktop. But there's a problem when I try to install it on my laptop. Everything is installed fine but when I install the ADT and then restart eclipse this error occurs, where it says something like adb error.

> DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
>   DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 2
>   ...
>   DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 600

I am using windows 7 64x and eclipse indigo (I have tried with other versions too) and my network card is a killer wireless n series. Has anyone faced this kind of problems before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to fact that Win7 prefers to return IPV6 address for localhost. The Solution is to force Eclipse IDE to use IPV4. See here how to do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327411/1363296

Comment: Thank you so much.For 6 months I have been struggling with this.Now it has been solved .Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Your ADB must be restarted restart adb server using following command in command prompt**

```
adb stop-server
adb start-serevr
```

It will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But I have tried that.Still this error persists.Really weird!!!

Comment: it says theres a DDMS error.I did stop the adb server and started it again it didnt help.Anyother suggestions?

Comment: Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection this is what it says.1.Turned on turned off adb 2.Tried with different eclipse versions.3.Disabled firewalls 4.Uninstalled and installed a number of times.Nothing worked.Any ideas?